# Real 4K in Android TV

Tags: sony, television, android-tv

I need create an application for Android TV with function slideshow. Images on the screen to be displayed in the resolution of 4K. And it's problem. For testing, I choose the model SONY BRAVIA X90C.
First of all, I tried to create a Web application and paste the image in the size 3840x2160. Opening the browser Opera this page turned out that the page is rendered in resolution 1920px width.
If i create a native app for android tv, can i get a true rendering in 4k resolution ?
Or I'll get 2K with scale to 4K ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes.

Bear in mind though you have to have a device that can output the required resolution over HDMI. Otherwise even though your app may be outputting 4k the resulting picture will be down-sampled when sent to the tv.

NVIDIA Shield Android TV is 4k compliant and would be my device of choice to use.

They also have very good tools with Visual Studio integration if you also wanted to make a game with 4k assets.